# how to assert response success in groovy unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, response

Hey I am trying to develop a sample app in groovy on grails. I have an action called login..which doesn't do anything except to render a page called login. I think there is no need to explicitly render any view called login inside the action, as my view name matches the action name.

```
def login = {

}
```

As I follow TDD, I want to assert that that response was successful. How do I do that in groovy unit testing?

Answer (score 2):

You can't unit test the HTTP response, as the controller is just a plain old groovy class when called from a unit test. You'll need to use an integration test (using a MockHttpServletRequest/Response) or use one of the functional testing plugins: gfunc, webtest, selenium etc

There should be plenty of examples of both integration and functional tests to be found via Google.

Comment: The Grails User Guide is a good place to start. An example of integration testing controllers: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.2%20Integration%20Testing